# Safely pass parameter to Controller via AJAX in Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, security, symfony, routes

I've got a question on how to best/safely pass parameters on an ajax request to my controller.

I've got these **two options** within my project using Symfony:

(1) I could pass parameters, like my entity id and a csrf token, via:

```
Routing.generate("my_update_route", {'id': entity.id, 'token' : token});
```

-> benefit of this approach would be, that I could check within my @Route annotation the correct parameter type with requirements:

```
@Route("/account/entity/update/{id}/{token}", name="my_update_route", 
        requirements={"id" = "\d+", "token" = "[a-z]+"})
```

-> but is passing the id and a security (csrf) token via this way (Url) the recommended way?

Or (2) Passing the variables via the post body, not in the url and I would loose the possibility to check with "requirements" the correct type automatically - but - the values are passed more safely to the server (of course when using https).

---

How do you normally pass your parameters when using AJAX requests? What is the most secure way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id and the token via URL without problem.

As you said the annotation @Route allow you to check parameters patterns (id => integer and token => string).

The token value doesn't necessarily have to be secret as mentioned in this [reference](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Csrf/CsrfProvider/CsrfProviderInterface.html).

Hope it will help you.

Comment: In which case (except for Form submission and login)  would I use the "Post Body " to Transfer data? So when updating E.g. An entity, I would Pass the required parameters within Routing generate

Comment: You simply set your data in the "Post Body" when you don't want let the user see them in the url.

Comment: Ok, using ajax he will never See the url. Is there any other security issue I need to be aware of?

Comment: I think the most important is the validation of the data send in the url. For example the validation of the token is valid, the id exist in the database, etc.